# Interpretation of Stories that depict Shiva and Vishnu as bodily?

Tags: scripture, shiva, vishnu, interpretation

How are we to interpret stories in scripture that seem to depict Shiva and Vishnu as corporeal, bodily beings?

We know that Shiva and Vishnu are eternal, immaterial, and omnipresent. So what does it mean when, for example, when a story says that Shiva swallowed poison and got a blue throat? How do we know how to interpret stories like these, and others?

Comment: many people can only think of God as a material Being. You may accept these stories either literally or figuratively according to your own mind. Is not the Lord of infinite Being and power? Is anyhting impossible for the Lord to have done, or do or become?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Because God is infinite I don't think it's possible for him to be finite.